Imprimir una variable de JS a HTML
Buen Día.
El día de hoy quiero imprimir una variable que se encuentra en JS y que esta misma me refleja en console.log pero quiero se vea reflejada en una pagina a lado de un texto de HTML al momento de realizar una consulta.
Quiero pasar de esto:
<strong>Federal:</strong><br>

A esto:
<strong>Federal:</strong><br> (junto el valor que debe imprimir)

Mi console.log es:
console.log(dtto);


Prueba poniéndolo en un <span> o en un <div> que tenga un atributo id= único, y con la propiedad innerHTML lo agregas a dicho elemento desde javascript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Hola! @masterguru entonces en la parte del Federal: agrego enseguida el  y la propiedad innerHTML va dirigida en la función de JS?

Ponlo así en el html: <strong>Federal:</strong><br><div id="unico"></div> y en el javascript, donde escribes el console.log pon una linea más y agrega esto a ver si te funciona: document.getElementById("unico").innerHTML = ddto

@masterguru si es lo que me dijiste en tu anterior comentario muchas gracias.

Hay varias formas en que puedes mostrar, agregar o imprimir el contenido de una variable en la salida al usuario.
Para ello, te vales del DOM, que es la representación en memoria del documento HTML que está cargado en la página.
Dado que, lo que muestras es un fragmento del HTML, estoy asumiendo, primero, que este fragmento va a estar contenido en un elemento estructural, por ejemplo, un DIV.
Hay varias estrategias para poder acceder a un elemento específico dentro del DOM, aquí, me valgo de la más directa y simple, que es asignarle un identificador (llamado id) al elemento que queremos acceder, dentro del HTML, y luego utilizar el método getElementById() para accederlo dentro de nuestro javascript.
Una vez hicimos eso, simplemente estoy agregando el texto dentro de ese elemento. Para ello me valgo de los métodos createTextNode() y [appendChild()][4], respectivamente.
Creo que el código habla por si mismo, pero si tienes dudas, puedes dejarme un comentario.


let dtto="Mi dato";
const miDiv = document.getElementById("miDiv");
const txtDtto = document.createTextNode(dtto);
miDiv.appendChild(txtDtto);
<div id="miDiv"><strong>Federal:</strong><br></div>



En este caso, el resultado es el equivalente a:
<div id="miDiv"><strong>Federal:</strong><br>Mi dato</div>

Otra posibilidad, desde mi punto de vista, mejor, es que tengamos preparado un elemento en el que vamos a mostrar esa información, y acceder directamente a él para mostrarla.
En este caso, además de los métodos que ya conocemos del ejemplo anterior, asigno el valor de la propiedad innerText


let dtto="Mi dato";
const miSpan = document.getElementById("dtto");
miSpan.innerText = dtto;
<strong>Federal:</strong><br><span id="dtto"></span>



Que produce el resultado equivalente a:
<strong>Federal:</strong><br><span id="dtto">Mi dato</span>

No voy a extender más esta respuesta, pero sirva esto como introducción. Si sigues la documentación de los métodos enlazados y buscas en Internet, encontrarás más maneras de realizarlo.
